# The closure of selfadjoint elements of an algebra whose spectrum consist of rational numbers

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be a seperable complex Hilbert space. What is the closure of the set of all self adjoint operators in $B(H)$ whose spectrum is a subset of the rational number $\mathbb{Q}$.

Apart from finite dimensional $C^*$ algebras what are some other examples of algebra with the following property:

"Every self adjoint  element can  be approximated with a self adjoint $a$ with $\delta(a)\subset \mathbb{Q} $"

Comment: If the spectral theorem holds in your algebra, for example in any von Neumann algebra, such is true, as one can approximate the spectral ,measure by one with point masses at the rationals. It seems likely this is almost like saying one can approximate by elements with finite spectrum.

Comment: In other words, the closure is all self-adjoint operators in $B(H)$, by J.E. Pascoe's argument (approximate the spectral resolution $E$ by replacing $E$ on a small interval $I$ by $\delta_q E(I)$, with $q\in I$).

Comment: [deleted earlier comment which arose from being slow]

Comment: @YemonChoi I think it is not true that every compact subset of the rational number is necessarilly a finit set for example the sequence 1/n goes to 0

Comment: You are quite right, Ali: I have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 3):

A unital C*-algebra has real rank zero if the self-adjoint elements with finite spectrum are norm-dense in the set of all self-adjoints. If a self-adjoint element has finite spectrum, then it is of the form $a=\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j p_j$ for $\lambda_j\in\mathbb{R}$ and pairwise orthogonal projections $p_j$ that sum to the unit. Choosing rational numbers $\lambda_j'$ close to $\lambda_j$, we see that $a$ is norm-close to $\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j' p_j$, which has finite spectrum contained in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Thus, in every unital C*-algebra of real rank zero, every self-adjoint element can be approximated by self-adjoint elements with finite spectrum contained in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Every von Neumann algebra (in particular, $B(H)$) has real rank zero.